# my decrypting program is doing the wrong thing

Tags: python, list, encryption

Today I made a .py file that decrypts strings encrypted with a vigenere square. I have gotten this far but I cant seem to add spaces to the ciphr list and encr_txt because it garbles the decrypted message. Instead of "message is, hello my name is slim shady", you get "message is, hellprvmwhwebwrw k  d thady", where as if i leave spaces out of encr_txt and the ciphr list I get a fine message. I do not know how to fix this there are no errors either, I just started coding in python a couple days ago so if its obvious i'm sorry. Also I know this could be done way easier but im learning lists so i chose to make it this way instead of something like this:

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711747/ascii-vigenere-cipher-not-decrypting-properly">Another question i found relating my problem but does not describe my situation</a>
```

Code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ^ encoding

# Encrypted text
# encr_txt = 'tkedobaxoudqrrffhhhalbmmcnedeo'
encr_txt = 'qexpg vy zeen ie wdrm elsmy'
#encr_list = list(encr_txt)
txtpos = 0
# Key to ^
key = 'james'
keypos = 0

limit = len(encr_txt)
limitpos = 0
# Vigenere square
ciphr = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ',
         'bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz a',
         'cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ab',
         'defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abc',
         'efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcd',
         'fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcde',
         'ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdef',
         'hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefg',
         'ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefgh',
         'jklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghi',
         'klmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghij',
         'lmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijk',
         'mnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijkl',
         'nopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklm',
         'opqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmn',
         'pqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmno',
         'qrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnop',
         'rstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopq',
         'stuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqr',
         'tuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrs',
         'uvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrst',
         'vwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstu',
         'wxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrtsuv',
         'xyz abcdefghijklmnopqrtsuvw',
         'yz abcdefghijklmnopqrtsuvwx',
         'z abcdefghijklmnopqrtsuvwxy',
         'abcdefghijklmnopqrtsuvwxyz ']

first = ciphr[0]
string = ''


def start():
    global limitpos
    limitpos += 1
    global keypos
    for i in ciphr:
        if keypos == len(key):
            keypos = 0
        else:
            pass
        if i[0] == key[keypos]:
            #print "%s, %s" % (i[0], i)
            global currenti
            currenti = i
            #print currenti
            finder()
            break
        else:
            pass

def finder():
    global keypos
    global txtpos
    done = False
    position = 0
    while done == False:
        for i in currenti[position]:
            if i == '_':
                pass

            if i == encr_txt[txtpos]:
                global string
                string = string + first[position]
                #print "message is, %s" % string
                keypos += 1
                txtpos += 1

                done = True
                if limitpos == limit:
                    print "message is, %s" % string
                    break
                else:
                    start()
            else:
                position += 1
                pass

start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding spaces to the table changes the way the cipher works. You can't expect to make that kind of change and not affect the way messages are encrypted and decrypted!

As an aside, the last row of your table is incorrect. It's identical to the first row, but it should have the space in the first position.

Comment: any idea on how to add spaces without garbling the message?

Comment: @PizzaCat You can't. The message you're trying to decrypt was encrypted using a cipher that skipped over the space characters in its input. You _have_ to leave the spaces alone to decrypt it correctly!

Comment: i was wondering if i coult write it like this https://pastebin.com/LCfhwRys